# What does a const value do in an anonymous struct field?

Tags: struct, go, constants, anonymous

Given the following code:

```
type NodeType int

const (
    NodeText NodeType = iota
    NodeAction
    // etc..
)

type ListNode struct {
    NodeType
}
```

What is the explanation of including the `NodeType` type as an anonymous field in the `ListNode` struct? Does it serve as some sort of identifier for the struct?

Answer (score 2):

For such an *anonymous* or *embedded field*, per [*The Go Programming Language Specification*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types),

> The unqualified type name acts as the field name.

In your case, you can write the following:

```
var node1 ListNode
node1.NodeType = NodeText
```

or

```
node2 := ListNode{NodeText}
```

or

```
node3 := ListNode{
    NodeType: NodeText,
}
```

All three create the same value.

Answer (score 2):

`NodeType` isn't a constant. It's a type, and it has been embedded into the `ListNode` struct.

> Struct types have the ability to contain anonymous or embedded fields.
>   This is also called embedding a type. When we embed a type into a
>   struct, the name of the type acts as the field name for what is then
>   an embedded field.

e.g. You would set the `NodeType` for a `ListNode` as per below:

```
ln := &ListNode{NodeType: NodeText}
fmt.Println(ln)
// Outputs: &{0}
```

Further reading: http://www.goinggo.net/2014/05/methods-interfaces-and-embedded-types.html (scroll down) and https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

Answer (score 2):

That is not an 'anonymous field' the language feature being used is called 'embedding' and it's sort of Go's way of addressing inheritance. In Go, if `StructA` embeds `StructB` then fields on `StructB` and methods with a receiving type of `StructB` will become directly accessible on `StructA`. Same rules for exported vs unexported apply however (ie unexported fields in `StructB` won't be accessible outside the packages scope like normal). I can't say why you want this value in all your structs, this is just an efficient way of doing it. At the end of the day it's just an int and you're just saving a few lines of code by not giving it an actual name, nothing more really.